# Magento 1.8.0.0 Shows all Product in Category regardless of limit.

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, product-collection, list.phtml

I'm trying to fix some nasty thing that happened to our store. We currently using Grid only display mode. Category has 192 products and settings are these: 
- List Mode: Grid Only; 
- Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values: 9,15,18,24,27,30; 
- Products per Page on Grid Default Value: 15;
- Allow All Products per Page: No
- Product listing Sort By: Best Value

It suppose to render 15 product and make all others available on other pages that should be selected through pagination.

Toolbar renders correct, It shows Grid Allowed Values in Dropdown. Pagination is also calculating number of pages correct (13 pages for 15 products per page options), but page rendered with all products from this category at once.

I've tried limit them by adding ?limit=30 to URL, but no reaction.

I've google it and found out that it could happen if collection is loaded before it is limited. Theme is customized, but mostly styles and html.

I even replaced customized /catalog/product/list.phtml with original one (from base), but it is still outputs all products at once.

local.xml is also not changing standard layout. 
Backend -> Catalog -> Manage Categories - > This Category -> Custom Design Tab is also with no customization.

Here what I have in list.phtml

Beginning:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

Grid mode loop:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid text-center row">
    <?php endif ?>

/* here is product image, name, price code */

<?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I hope you are not using ajax auto load method. Like this http://turnkeye.com/blog/loading-products-with-ajax/

Comment: @AdarshKhatri No, we didn't changed core functions. They supposed to load as usual.

Comment: Then, I would replace original catalog.xml file - `path_to_your_theme/layout/catalog.xml` and see if it helps. Also could you give your live link here?

Comment: Yeah, I've played with catalog.xml all directives are remained unchanged. Page itself is here http://doorsandbeyond.com/interior-door-handles

Comment: I even loaded category in default Magento theme (changed Custom Design dropdown in Category's configuration). It does not any change. You can see in screenshot here: https://yadi.sk/i/AFSaqTi1g4vbJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think somewhere core function is customized. For example this file - `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php`
Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050587/magento-limit-the-number-of-products-shown-with-in-the-new-products-block).

Check your `app/code/local` folder and check if it has `mage/catalog/block/product/new.php` file. If it is there, remove/rename it for testing.

Also, some extension might have playing role, you need to disable all external extension from `etc/modules` and see if that helps.

Only problem I can see is your system not counting products right for the pages.

If all of these doesn't helps, I would replace all core files in `app/code/core/mage` with clean files of same version.

**But remember make backup of all the files and database before doing any of these.**

Comment: Hi @Adarsh

I've checked '/app/code/local' there's no modification on catalog view. As well as in New.php. Moreover, I've replaced core files in '/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product' with original files, flushed caches, but nothing happened. It is still generating all products at once. 

Now I'll dig into extensions.

Comment: Maybe it could help. This is result of '<?php echo $_productCollection->getSelect(); ?>'

http://pastebin.com/adXJF3ef

Comment: One more strange thing that Sort by and Sorting asc desc also not working. I mean there is no reaction when changing sort position and direction.

Comment: Then it could be your `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml`, try replacing org. file in phtml as well as php file for both.

Comment: Finally I found what was the cause for this bug. Extension named Qubit Universal Variable (Tag manager). Thanks for your contribution. I will Accept your answer as it guided me to find the cause.

Comment: That's it, you did it.